# How to push the particular results file values to db in jmeter by using JDbc or jsr223 sampler

Tags: jmeter

How Do that in jmeter by using JDbc or JSr223sampler,after completion of execution generate jtl/CSV results file,to take the results file particular values like samplers,average response time,90 percentage values and convert milli seconds and push to DB,how do the process tell me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Which DB? There is [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) which have a couple of implementations, one of them - `InfluxDbBackendListenerClient` allows storing all (or specified) [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) into [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/)

See [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2) for comprehensive steps on installation and configuration of JMeter and InfluxDB for real-time results storing

Comment: thanks for giving replay,i am using my sql db